# How to Manage View Title according to Contextual Filters

Tags: drupal-views

I want to use one common View to list Donations to each different organization (I have a lot), manageing each different View instance via contextual filters.

e.g. mysite/myView/9/2017, where :

- 9 = Contribution Page ID (which is organization specific)
- 2017 = Contribution Year

This works fine for filtering, but, beyond this, I would like the page Title to contain the Contribution Page **Name**.

I can, of course have a Title in the form of "Contributions 9" (using %1 to override the Title), but "9" does not speak a lot.

I have tried a solution, consisting in specifying the Contribution Page Name as a 3rd Contextual Filter and overriding the Page Title with this %3 filter : when I do that, the following URL mysite/myView/9/2017/"my Contribution Page" provides me with the correct title, but then, the View displays no result.

Am I missing sth ? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't quite make out all your requirements from your description - but I do have an example that (possibly) comes close to this. I don't use contextual filters though - I use Exposed Filters to identify which of 150 Contribution pages - specific Donations belong to:

[image]

Note that the URL in this case is:
/donations-via-group-contribution-pages?financial_type=All&contribution_page=43

So you could pass in that URL (or for any other contribution_page_id) -> and then have a screen for a sub-organization;

Thus far I've only used contextual filters for Drupal Commerce Views -> with a Contextual filter for Drupal userid -> so that we can then have permissions to only show Orders that belong to a specific user;

Comment: Thank you Karin : if I understand well, what I want to get in the Title, you display it as a filter value (exposed) : not a bad idea ! But what if the user resets the filter ? (+ I have several filters in my Views, which will be confusing). Anyway, however, I will dig the idea : I can, may-be, mix the 2 filters : contextual for actual filtering + exposed for the display. I keep the post open, in case other ideas occur.

Comment: People can change/reset the contextual filter too -

Comment: Yes, but only via the URL by hand (I only know this way), which is not intuitive.

Comment: BTW, I don't have this generic "RESET" button in my Views (I use 7.x 3.18) (I have to reset each filter individually) : is it an option that I don't know, or do you use a different version ?

Comment: Install the Better Exposed Filters module

Comment: Thank you Karin, I will have a look at this module ; btw, do you know some others that could be usefull to me ? (I already use Data Export, Calc, PDF display + I have tested VBO with a limited success)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Karin, I think I have a better understanding now :

When I want to set membership_type (alpha-numeric) as a filter, Views interprets it as membership_type_id (integer) : this is the case in the URL :

- for exposed filter : https://.../myView/?membership_type=56
- as well as for contextual filter : https://.../myView/56

If I set the alphanumeric membership_type (alphanumeric instead) (e.g. "Catéchisme" in my case), then the View is empty : thus, I can't override the View Title with this parameter.

But it is not the case for the exposed filter in the View itself which displays the alphanumeric value of membership_type (e.g. "Catéchisme" in my case), as suggested by Karin.

Finally I will set the alphanumeric membership_type as :

- an exposed filter in the View ("Organisation" in the screen shot here under)
- a contextual filter in the URL (with the membership_type_id integer
  value)
- a display filter in the URL (also with the membership_type_id integer
  value)

such as : https://.../myView/56?membership_type=56

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Doing so, if the user resets the exposed filter in the View, the filtering information is not displayed anymore, but the View remains filtered.

Comment: I removed that image you shared as it contained phone numbers etc. of what looks like real people; well done on your view by the way - it looks great;